# Crafter cms: how to download zip file for windows

Tags: java, crafter-cms

Hi team i am new to crafter cms .I am following the https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/getting-started/quick-start-guide.html#installing-crafter-cms-from-archive-download
I am using windows 10 .but in the http://craftercms.org/downloads there is no zip file .
there is only tar.gz files are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crafter CMS doesn't run directly on Windows, instead, you should use Docker to run it.

Here is the guide: https://docs.craftercms.org/current/getting-started/quick-start-guide.html#running-craftercms-in-docker